# Homebrew postinstall php exception

Tags: php, homebrew

I'm trying to install php 7.2.11 with Homebrew (running Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13.3). Before running the install command, I cleaned out all of my previous Homebrew php directories, ran doctor, etc. When I ran `brew install php`, it said that "postinstall php did not complete successfully". I then ran

`HOMEBREW_DEBUG=1 brew -v postinstall php`

The output says

`An exception occurred within a child process:
  Errno::EEXIST: File exists @ syserr_fail2_in -/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.11/pecl`

The named file is actually a symlink:

`pecl -> /usr/local/lib/php/pecl`

But /usr/local/lib/php/pecl does not exist. (I'm not looking to necessarily install any PECL extensions.)

Can anyone tell me what this error means and more importantly, how to rectify it?

Comment: a year later, I am asking the same question. This error occured for me as well, upggrading to PHP 7.4.0. I do note that I had pecl installed previously, and running `pecl version` in the terminal still functions. @buckthorn did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @DJEddieJ I honestly don't remember how I eventually got around this. It was probably wiping out a bunch of directories in Cellar and starting from scratch, more or less. Homebrew is great when it works, and not good when it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I ran into the same problem when installing php@5.6 using `homebrew`. I was stuck on it and now abandoned this way to install older versions of php. Below is roughly what I had done.

First I removed that dangling symbolic link. As a backup I temporarily stored the link elsewhere. Then I re-ran the `postinstall`. This time the output said

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
```

Actually it was because of a newer version of openssl, v1.1, installed earlier. So in that directory it was /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.1.0.dylib. Then I had to downgrade `openssl`:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@1.1
```

and installed the older version following [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/47348#issuecomment-560001981). (not an easy thing to do, as `homebrew` does not support installing an older version explicitly.)

Then I ran `postinstall` again and the dangling symbolic link reappeared. So I thought it was created during `postinstall`. I guess `postinstall` had planned to first create the symbolic link, and create the actual file later. But the actual creation was interrupted by incompatible dependencies. Removing it and re-running `postinstall`, I got

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.64.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.40/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
```

Similarly, this was another incompatible, older dependency. I lost my patience and then abandoned resorting to `homebrew`.

Actually, you can directly install other versions of php following [this](https://php-osx.liip.ch/).